# Ubuntu genome session is broken by an linux application build by pyinstaller when it's running by desktop shortcut and closed

Tags: linux-kernel, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qwebview, genome

I have built an linux application by python, pyqt5, django and pyinstaller and I have added desktop shortcut to lunch from start menu. When I run the app on command line there is no problem. But when I run the app by desktop shortcut and exit it then the app close everything on genome session and log out.

The app is working well. Only the problem is happening when I exit the app.
My system is Ubuntu 18.04 and I keep latest upgraded.

- The app use QWebEngineView on pyqt5.

Comment: This is my system logs.

Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0

[pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

Comment: On Stack Overflow comments are badly suited for multi-line logs. Moreover, because these logs describes your problem, they should be added to the question post itself (via [edit]ing it).